# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
this is my quote of jquery:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

I have searcher for two hours, this project can work in other pc. In my pc ,it just can't... help!

Comment: aaaaaannnnnd the bootstrapI library ??

Comment: check if jquery is getting loaded

Comment: Are you included bootstrap in your file or any other equilant file that file contains the .modal() method

Comment: @KMS I have already included bootstrap

Comment: Can u check the order of files jquery is first and bootsrap is next

Comment: take look at this link http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`modal()` is not a standard method of jQuery.

You will need to include another library that has a `modal()` method - such as jQueryUI, or Bootstrap.

If you have included one of those libraries you need to ensure that the URL to the file is correct, and that you have included it *after* `jquery.js`.

Comment: In that case it's not loading properly. Is the URL to it correct and have you included it *after* jQuery? We need to see how you've included it.

Comment: I have updated two picture. I use webstorm. when I press crtl. It can find their path

Comment: thanks buddy! I solve it. I have a whrong order of jquery and bootstrap. But can you tell more details of that. I don't know why?

Comment: bootstrap.js relies on jquery.js, so jQuery has to be included first.

Answer (score 0):

You already include the *bootstrap.main.js* but still you have a problem, then, there may be issues of `.JS` file sequence as the query is the core library file so it is always included a first and other plugins works * (which are depended on jQuery) *

So, My suggestion is to rearrange your `.JS` files and try once again.